# Snowflake create table like another table but set all columns to nullable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, nullable, create-table

as the subject line says, I would like to automatically create tables based on a list of tables in an excel, but if these are tables ending with _ERR, I want to strip any non-null limitations (a flaw in the old system).

Is there a way to do that? Just the actual statement, the rest of the logic is covered.

So something like :

```
CREATE TABLE … LIKE ... SET NULLABLE
```

would be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TABLE <table_name> LIKE <source_table>

then use alter to remove the NULL.

ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN c1 DROP NOT NULL;

Answer (score 1):

This is not a thing you can do natively with Snowflake's SQL variant. You'll need to script this out yourself.

Comment: ok thanks for the information, unfortunately, but still that is the answer, then

Answer (score 0):

you can create you statements by awk

```
awk  'FS="_" { if($NF=="ERR") print "create table like",$0 , "as nullable;"; else print "create table like",$0} ' file

o/p
    create table like table_1
    create table like table_2
    create table like table_3_ERR as nullable;
    create table like table_4
```

where i guess file includes below table names.

```
cat file
table_1
table_2
table_3_ERR
table_4
```

Comment: hi, thanks. As mentioned the logic is not the issue, but the actual statement :)

Comment: so tobrepeat, the SQL is the problem, not some ksh